# Are crons executed globally or per app instance (i.e. load dependent)?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

If I define a cron in App Engine to execute "**every 10 minutes**" - does that mean:

(a):

- `"every 10 minutes per app instance (i.e. load dependent)"`

(b):

- `"every 10 minutes globally across all instances of the application" (i.e. load independent)`?

Comment: A large part of the point of App Engine is that you don't have to care a great deal about instances, or how many your app runs on.

Answer (score 1):

It is once globally every 10 minutes.  Note that the interval refers to the time *between* jobs.  So job 2 will start 10 minutes after job 1 finishes.  This might be important if your job is long-running (e.g., if it takes 5 minutes to run, then it will actually start every 15 minutes if you specify "every 10 minutes").